# tags on an element's children

Tags: python, xml.etree

The following code (or rather, code very much like it) has been doing my head in all day. I'm out of ideas.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as etree

parent = etree.Element(etree.QName('http://www.example.com', tag='parent'))
child_a = etree.Element(etree.QName('http://www.example.com', tag='child'))
child_a.text='Bill'
parent.append(child_a)
child_b = etree.Element(etree.QName('http://www.example.com', tag='child'))
child_b.text='Barry'
parent.append(child_b)
print(etree.tostring(parent))

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "Lib\xml\etree\ElementTree.py", line 1120, in tostring
  File "Lib\xml\etree\ElementTree.py", line 812, in write
  File "Lib\xml\etree\ElementTree.py", line 880, in namespaces
  File "Lib\xml\etree\ElementTree.py", line 1046, in _raise_serialization_error
TypeError: cannot serialize <xml.etree.ElementTree.QName object at 0x0000000222B2198> (type QName)
```

It's not letting me add two children to an element if both children have the same qualified name. Is there any way around this (using etree, because it's too late to swap out my xml writer before tomorrow)?

Comment: What version of Python are you using? I'm running Python 2.6.7 and I can run your code just fine: one parent, two children. It appears out that `xml.etree.ElementTree` was updated in Python 3.2: http://docs.python.org/release/3.2/whatsnew/3.2.html#elementtree - perhaps you can run your code in an earlier version of Python to see if that helps?

Comment: I've just run it without any problems in Python 3.2 (except that the last line should be `print(etree.tostring(parent))`).  If this isn't your exact code, perhaps the problem is in the section you didn't post.

Comment: The version was 2.7.0 and I've since ran the code without problem with 2.7.2 on my laptop while I was trying to illustrate the problem to somebody else. I think it might be a bug which only affects that version.

It doesn't really help me though, because the code I'm supposed to be delivering is on an embedded python, so I'm locked into 2.7.0 for the release tomorrow (and it's an obvious bug so I'm guessing it was fixed by 2.7.1), so I still need a workaround of some description.

Comment: Also I've fixed the typo -- that was just made during transcription (I didn't copy+paste because I wrote the posted code in the interpreter). That was the just the simplest example I could devise which illustrated the exact problem.

Comment: @ovangle Could you swap to lxml? It also provides the etree interface.

Comment: That's a good idea -- I'll just package a version of lxml with the custom script I'm supposed to be delivering and import from that rather than what has been embedded in our main product. That *should* be problem solved, I don't know why it didn't occur to me before.